# creating trigger inserting UNIX_TIMESTAMP() to a log table

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin, unix-timestamp

Hi im stuck on the syntax of making this trigger to insert values to my log table. Using the sql tab inside phpmyadmin an error appears before executing the sql statement

```
`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 8 `
```

here is my sql statement in creating a trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_insert_list  
AFTER INSERT ON list FOR EACH ROW  
BEGIN  
    INSERT INTO log (user_id, action, date_log)  
    VALUES (
        NEW.user_id,  
        NEW.action, 
        UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
    );
END
```

Comment: Did you make sure to change the delimiter first?

Comment: @Jack could you care to expound on that? im a bit confused. and by the way i was following this tutorial on net tuts http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/databases/introduction-to-mysql-triggers/

Comment: You can find information about the delimiter in the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your trigger like follows:

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER testref 
BEFORE INSERT ON test1FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT INTO test2 SET a2 = NEW.a1;
DELETE FROM test3 WHERE a3 = NEW.a1;
UPDATE test4 SET b4 = b4 + 1 WHERE a4 = NEW.a1;
END;
|
delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a 100% working example:

**Table `demo`**

```
CREATE TABLE `demo` (
    `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `text` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `updated_at` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

**Trigger on INSERT**

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE TRIGGER `updated_at__on_insert`
BEFORE INSERT
ON `demo`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   SET new.updated_at = UNIX_TIMESTAMP();
END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

**Trigger on UPDATE**

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE TRIGGER `updated_at__on_update`
BEFORE UPDATE
ON `demo`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   SET new.updated_at = UNIX_TIMESTAMP();
END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

p.s. I was looking for such a solution for my CMS EFFCORE.